# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on MultiChoiceMode listview with fragment

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm inflating Fragemnt using FragmentPager on MainActivity and getting

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2

on listview Item long Click.

```
list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        list.setMultiChoiceModeListener(mModeListener);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

// listner

 private AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener mModeListener = new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        // private int selectedRows;

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                              long id, boolean checked) {
            mode.invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.cab, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            mode = null;
        }

    };
```

Comment: Post the code for onItemClickListener.

Comment: Where is `onItemClickListener` method in code?

Comment: starting new activity on item click but need to check list item on Item long click not on item click.